# Vast Amount of Data Needs to be Matched

Tags: count, excel-formula, match

I have an Excel Workbook... in Column 'F' is a list of 95 companies, in random order through time, as they have submitted tickets.

3174 of them.

In column 'I', are the SUBJECTS of these tickets.

375 of them.

*I* want to know how I can get the most common occurrence for each subject, as submitted by each company.

If company 'ACME' in Row 15, occurs 89 times throughout the 3174, of those 89 times, which of the 374 subjects occur most frequently?

Thank you.
D.Pierce

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula:

```
=INDEX(B1:B8,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIFS(A1:A8,"comp1",B1:B8,B1:B8)),COUNTIFS(A1:A8,"comp1",B1:B8,B1:B8),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]